# How to write the console application that register the events and it should be called whenever the radio state is changed through the windows setting

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to understand how to register the events using C++ WinRT using console application.

```
void  Radio_StateChanged(Windows::Devices::Radios::Radio const& sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args) {
    printf("\t Radio_StateChanged %ls\n",sender.Name().c_str());

}
void Initialize()
{
    auto radio10 = Radio::GetRadiosAsync().get();

    for (Radio const& r : radio10) {
        if (r.Kind() == RadioKind::MobileBroadband)
        {
            r.StateChanged(&Radio_StateChanged);
            printf("\t Radio Change enter\n");
            if (r.State() == RadioState::Off)
            {               

                printf("\t Radio Change ON\n");
                r.SetStateAsync(RadioState::On);
                break;
            }
            else if (r.State()==RadioState::On)
            {

                r.SetStateAsync(RadioState::Off);
                printf("\t Radio Change OFF\n");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm able to compile the code successfully but if I try to enable or disable the Mobile Broadband through **windows setting** I'm not seeing any events called. If I do the same **Programactically** the method Radio_StateChanged event is called . **How can get the StateChanged notification in 64 bit console application whenever the radio state is changed via windows settings.** I have Mobile Broadband radio present.

Thank you :)

Comment: You're probably not letting the system dispatch events/messages (which is implicit when you run a window app). Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#a-deeper-dive-into-winrtresume_foreground with CreateDispatcherQueueController and Win32 message pump

Comment: The simplest way to make sure the calling thread is dispatching messages is to spin up a [MessageBoxW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) after everything is set up. Try to see if that is sufficient.

Comment: I tried with co_await it's not working. The problem which I'm facing is If I try to enable/disable cellular(mobile broadband) going to taskbar I'm not able to listen any statechanged event called

Comment: Tried to refer [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/RadioManager/cppwinrt/RadioModel.cpp) but Xaml is used .Moreover  I need to write in a console application. So any changes to be done to the code in order to run in console application.

Comment: how can I get event listened whenever radio state is changed through windows setting using console application

Comment: Event raised by a state change in the radio represented by this object. When a USB Bluetooth radio is removed or otherwise goes offline, no state change is [reported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.statechanged?view=winrt-20348).