# How to register the events using C++ WinRT in console application?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, mobile-broadband-api

I'm trying to understand how to register the events using C++ WinRT using console application.

```
void Radio_StateChanged(Windows::Devices::Radios::Radio const& sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args) {
    printf("\t Radio_StateChanged %ls\n",sender.Name().c_str());
}

void Initialize()
{
    auto radio10 = Radio::GetRadiosAsync().get();

    for (Radio const& r : radio10) {
        if (r.Kind() == RadioKind::MobileBroadband) {
            r.StateChanged(&Radio_StateChanged);
            printf("\t Radio Change enter\n");
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm able to compile the code successfully but if I try to enable or disable the Mobile Broadband / cellular through Windows setting I'm **not seeing any events called**.
How can get the StateChanged notification in 64-bit console application whenever the radio state is changed via windows settings?
I have Mobile Broadband radio present. I also referred the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/RadioManager/cppwinrt/RadioModel.cpp) but it's more on Xaml.

I wanted to listen the event called whenever the RadioState is changed via Windows Settings / Task bar.

What changes should be done in the code in order to run in 64-bit console application?
Is there a need of `co_await` and dispatcher in order to run in console application?
Should I need to use Xaml for console application?

Comment: Stop re-asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69342494/1889329) all over again. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum where *"bumping"* a question is common.

Comment: @IInspectable I made some changed so wanted to ask again . So if you have any suggestion please let me know on this query :)

Comment: Suggestions: Adhere to the rules around here, specifically, don't create multiple accounts, and don't re-post the same question. If you have anything to add, do it on the question you initially asked. There's an `Edit` link underneath it for that purpose.